# Split column into multiple columns using str_match

Tags: r, split, stringr

I want to split column into multiple columns by matching the patterns

```
test <- data.frame("id" = c("Albertson's Inc.","Albertson's Inc."), "V3" = c("Reiterates FY 2004, Significant Developments, 2 June 2004, 53 words, (English)(Document MULTI00020050122e06201fkk)","EBITDA Hits Four Year Low,  Stock Diagnostics, 16:00 GMT, 9 June 2004, 245 words, (English)(Document STODIA0020040609e0690006g)"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

So far the code I'm using to get desired result is like

```
library(stringr)
    df <- as.data.frame(str_match(test$V3, "^(.*)GMT,(.*),(.*)words,(.*)Document (.*)$")[,-1], stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I'm having two issues with above code
First it does not show results when GMT is missing secondly I want "id" column in the output df as well, any suggestion or different approach should I use for  results please share thanks to all the moderators programmers for such a helpful forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not 100% sure about your "GTM" problem. here is my try:

your rep data:

```
test <- data.frame("id" = c("Albertson's Inc.","Albertson's Inc."), "V3" = c("Reiterates FY 2004, Significant Developments, 2 June 2004, 53 words, (English)(Document MULTI00020050122e06201fkk)","EBITDA Hits Four Year Low,  Stock Diagnostics, 16:00 GMT, 9 June 2004, 245 words, (English)(Document STODIA0020040609e0690006g)"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

code:

```
library(tidyverse)    
test$V3 %>% map(~str_split(.,",(?!\\s*\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2})|(?<=\\))(?=\\()") %>% unlist %>% trimws) %>%
        do.call(rbind,.) %>%
        cbind(test["id"],.)
```

result:

```
#                    id                         1                            2           3         4         5                                    6
#    1 Albertson's Inc.        Reiterates FY 2004     Significant Developments 2 June 2004  53 words (English) (Document MULTI00020050122e06201fkk)
#    2 Albertson's Inc. EBITDA Hits Four Year Low Stock Diagnostics, 16:00 GMT 9 June 2004 245 words (English) (Document STODIA0020040609e0690006g)
```